# Nesting of classes and this value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, nested, this, prototype

Can I write nested classes in Javascript?

```
function A()
{
    this.a;
    this.B = function()
    {
      this.ab ;
      this.C  = function()
      {
         this.ab = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

If the above code is correct,then

```
1.How do I declare an object of type B
2.Whose property is  ab.A() 's  or B() 's?.
3.Inside B() where does the 'this' points to.To A() Or to B()?
```

Comment: JavaScript does not have classes, only objects and functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract:

Calling to function without using `new` operator means that `this` will be refer to object in which that function was created.
For global variables this object is window object.
Calling using `new` -  function  behave as constructor like in classes and `this` refers to this instance which will been created

**1.How do I declare an object of type B**

First way( as a curiosity ) - by calling to `A` without using  `new` operator `this` will be refer to `window`object and `B` method and all other what was declared with `this` leaks to global scope because `A == window.A`  => `true`

```
A(); 
var b = new B; // means => new window.B  //parentheses can be ommited if you invoking without arguments  
alert( ab )  // alerts 'inside A'  -> value from code presented below
```

or from instance of A:

```
new new A().B  // means => new ( new A ).B
```

Be careful.

**2.Whose property is  ab.A() 's  or B() 's?.**

As above, it depends of how we'll accessing to it:

```
 function A()
    {
        this.ab = "inside A";
        this.B = function()
        {
          this.ab = "inside B";
          this.c  = function()
          {  
             this.ab = "inside C";
          }
        }
    };
```

Check this out

```
var a = new A;
a.ab // "inside A"
a.B(); // in B now 'this' refers to 'a', 'a.ab' will be replaced to 'ab' from inside 'B'
a.ab // "inside B"
```

but

```
var a = new A;
a.ab // "inside A"
var b = new a.B;
a.ab // "inside A"
b.ab // "inside B"

// and now
b.c() 
b.ab // "inside C" and so on:)
```

**3.Inside B() where does the 'this' points to.To A() Or to B()?**

As above:)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the "classes" will be instance-specific. Are you sure you want that? You might be looking for something more along the lines of:

```
function A() {
    // ...
}

A.B = function() {
    // ...
};

var one = new A();
var two = new A.B();
```

Although the "nested" classes won't be able to access "private members" because JavaScript doesn't have those in the first place.

---

As for your example:

1. You would create an instance of A, say `new A()`, and access `B`, say `new new A().B()`<sup>1</sup>, or replacing `new A()` with a variable.
2. Neither, it's an empty statement for now... but it would be a property of the `B` instance.
3. To an instance of `B` (unless `Function.call` or `Function.apply` is used).

---

<sup>1</sup> Yes, it works!

Answer (score 1):

It's very unorthodox, but there's nothing stopping you from nesting constructor functions in JavaScript.

From your example, you can access the B function from an instance of A:

```
var someA = new A();
var someB = new someA.B();
```

To answer your other question:

```
 this.B = function() {
      this.ab = 0;
      this.c  = function() {
         this.ab++;
      }
    }
```

What `this` refers to inside of B depends on how `B` is **invoked**.  If you call `B` as a constructor, with the `new` keyword, `this` will be a new object inheriting from B's prototype.

If you call B without `new`, it will be treated as a method, and `this` will be the instance of A on which the method was called.

And so on with C.  If C is called with `new`, `this` inside of C will be a new object inheriting from C's prototype.  Or C can be a method of B, which makes a lot more sense.  Is something like this what you're wanting:

```
function A() {
    this.a;
    this.B = function() {
         this.ab = 0;
         this.c  = function() {
             this.ab++;
         }
    }
}

var someA = new A();
var someB = new someA.B();

console.log(someB.ab); //0
someB.c();
console.log(someB.ab); //1
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxt3g/)

---

Finally, note that, though nesting constructors like this isn't too common, there's nothing stopping you from adding to `B`'s prototype just like you would any other constructor

```
function A() {
    this.a;
    this.B = function() {
      this.ab = 0;
      this.c  = function() {
         this.ab++;
      }
    }
    this.B.prototype.foo = function() { alert("Bar " + this.ab) };
}

var someA = new A();
var someB = new someA.B();

console.log(someB.ab);
someB.c();
console.log(someB.ab);
someB.foo();   //Bar 1
```

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xxt3g/2/)

Comment: Which object is referred by 'this' inside B().Object of A or objet of B?

Comment: Can i use  'this' like <pre>
function A()
    {
        this.a;
        this.B = function()
        {
          this.ab ;
          this.C  = function()
          {
             this.ab = 0;//this refers to B
             this.a =1;//this refers to A

          }
        }
    }

Comment: Understood..Thanks Adam Rackis

Comment: @JinuJD - sure thing.  For completeness I added one more edit